# How to force refresh all entities in Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm wondering if it is possible to refresh all entities from data model as opposite to refresh them one by one.

Something like entities.RefreshAll();

Comment: Why? This would be a very expensive operation -- could potentially take a very long time for little benefit. Why not just dispose the `ObjectContext` and start a new one?

Comment: @Craig

We use PRISM in WPF and when we resolve Data Model then it always returns singleton, only one instance per run.

It is a good thing for us.

We need to refresh all Entities after synchronization, usually from time to time only.

It would be really great if we could just use "entities.RefreshAll();"

Regards,
Daniel Skowroński

Comment: You do *not* want to use a singleton OC. This will hurt you in memory use and performance areas. The OC is a unit of work. The unit of work in your app can't be "the whole lifetime of the app." You need to reconsider your design; it is currently broken.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use this code:

```
public void RefreshAll()
{
     // Get all objects in statemanager with entityKey 
     // (context.Refresh will throw an exception otherwise) 
     var refreshableObjects = (from entry in context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
                                                EntityState.Added 
                                               | EntityState.Deleted 
                                               | EntityState.Modified 
                                               | EntityState.Unchanged)
                                      where entry.EntityKey != null
                                      select entry.Entity);

     context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, refreshableObjects);
}
```

I wrote another couple of ways of refreshing with EF:

http://christianarg.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/entityframework-refreshall-loaded-entities-from-database/

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.